# WPF: NodeChanged event not firing

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF app that binds a DataGrid to an XML document using XmlDataProvider. Everything works fine except that I'm trying to "save"/write to XML file on NodeChanged event, instead of having a button or other user-triggered mechanism. Unfortunately, NodeChanged handler that I created is not being picked up. Would appreciate any help to figure out why it's not fired.

XAML:

```
  <Grid Name="Grid" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <XmlDataProvider x:Name="MyData" Source="Data.xml" XPath="Nodes/Node" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,50">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,276,0,0" Name="SaveButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="SaveButton_Click" />
  </Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
      MyData.Source = new Uri(appPath + "/Data.xml");
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      string source = MyData.Source.LocalPath;
      MyData.Document.Save(source); 
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MyData.Document.NodeChanged += new XmlNodeChangedEventHandler(Document_NodeChanged);
    }

    void Document_NodeChanged(object sender, XmlNodeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Node changed");
    }
  }
}
```

XML data file:

```
<Nodes>
  <Node Value="test1" />
  <Node Value="test3" />
  <Node Value="ttt" />
</Nodes>
```

To reproduce, you can just paste the above into a new WPF app, name XML data file Data.xml, place it into bin/Debug of the project, and add it to the project as "existing item".

**UPDATE**

Thanks Robert for pointing out the issue!

Here's an even more interesting situation. If you just add a LayoutUpdated event handler to the MainWindow to my sample code as below, you will get very weird behavior in that NodeChanged event will actually be fired if a totally unrelated MessageBox is displayed:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool event_activated = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        MyData.Source = new Uri(appPath + "/Data.xml");
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string source = MyData.Source.LocalPath;
        MyData.Document.Save(source);  
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyData.Document.NodeChanged += new XmlNodeChangedEventHandler(Document_NodeChanged);
    }

    private void Document_NodeChanged(object sender, XmlNodeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Node changed");
    }

    private void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        if (!event_activated)
        {
            event_activated = true;
            MessageBox.Show("LayoutUpdated"); // <-- NodeChanged is fired with this one line of code, and not fired if you comment this line out!!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't fire because the value of the node doesn't change, only the attribute that happens to be named Value. It is stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.XML.XMLDOCUMENT.NODECHANGED%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> Occurs when the Value of a node belonging to this document has been changed.
>   ... 
>   This event only applies to nodes that have a value.

How about using DataGrid.CellEditEnding or DataGrid.RowEditEnding instead?

**Update:**

You are correct, the NodeChanged will fire for attributes as well. I did find the problem in your nice repro app though. If I comment out your constructor code, it all works. You already set the source in Xaml. It seems that this code fires an internally handled exception which puts the XmlDataProvider in a corrupt state.

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     //string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
     //MyData.Source = new Uri(appPath + "/Data.xml");
  }
```

You can see the exception in debug output. WPF seems to like to fail silently and leave you wondering.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but isn't attribute a type of a node according to documentation of XmlNode.Value and XmlNodeType enum?
<br /><br />
In any case, I changed my XML data file layout to: 
<br /><br />
<pre><code>
<Nodes>
  <Node>Test 1</Node>
</Nodes>
</code></pre>
<br /><br />
And changed XAML accordingly. The app still doesn't fire NodeChanged event, but writes to the XML file just fine.
<br /><br />
Regarding DataGrid-based events, I'm planning to have multiple components all tied to the same XmlDataProvider source, so it would be painful to wire events for all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling with formatting. Below is the new XML structure.

Comment: <Nodes>
  <Node>Test 1</Node>
  <Node>Test 2</Node>
</Nodes>

Comment: Thanks Robert! It does indeed work when commented out. Quick question if you don't mind. What is the exception? All I can see is "The thread '<No Name>' (0xb80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).". Is there a way to see more? Sorry, I'm new to .Net and WPF.

Comment: I added another interesting tidbit that actually makes NodeChanged to be fired, but I have no idea why it is so.